# TLS version used in JDK 8

Tags: java, tls1.2

We initialise our SSL context with the following code and are running on Java 8.

```
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
```

Since Java 8 uses TLSv1.2 by default? Does it mean the above code will start sending TLSv1.2 requests if my server supports it.

Want to understand if "SSL" protocol name is just an alias but java runtime starts sending the requests with default TLS version.

**UPDATE**

I ran my code against "https://www.google.co.in/" and found this in fiddler

```
A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.

Version: 3.3 (TLS/1.2
```

And also if i change my protocol to TLSv1 which only supports 1.0. Then Fiddler tells me

```
A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.

Version: 3.1 (TLS/1.0)
```

So, I guess the above code with "SSL" protocol name should work well with TLS 1.2 servers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In Java 7, server side default TLS version was 1.2. In Java 8 both server and client have default TLS version 1.2.

As TLS version is backward compatible on both side unless server is configured strictly to specific version should not be an issue.

Comment: thanks for the reply. ..my question is also whether mentioning the protocol name as "SSL" while SSLContext initilziation as per my code will point to TLSv1.2 ?

Comment: If you want to use default then call should use getDefault instead of getInstance.

Comment: yes understand that...but wanted to check if the protocol name is just an alias but java runtime selects the default TLS version for protocol...i have updated my question if it was not clear.

Comment: Require some experiment by setting different value and tracing packets using tcpdump. The API doc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#SSLContext is not very clear.

Comment: i ran my code against and captured the request through fiddler...at least fiddler says that it is sending TLS 1.2 request ...updated the post above